# Refactor a for loop of Active Users to improve speed

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop, lapply

I have a dataframe of Users with their `DATE_CREATION` and `DATE_DELETION`.

```
ACTIVE_USERS <- data.frame(Date=c("2022-01-12", "2022-02-18", "2022-03-22", "2022-04-10", "2022-07-15" ) ,
                           USER_ID=c("user123","user311","user245","user245","user213"),
                           DATE_DELETION=c("2022-04-11","2022-04-12","2022-03-28","2022-07-12","2022-08-11"))
```

I am trying to create a graph that will show *Nb of Active Users each day* (we consider Active if simply existing).
For that, I wrote the below script that seems to do the job, but is **extremely slow** and takes a few hours to render (because I have much more dates than in above dataframe example). Any help to improve the speed of this script is welcomed, see below my current method:

I created a dataframe sequence of Dates from 1st date of creation to last, and I joined these two dataframes by Date of Creation

```
Axis_X_Date <- data.frame(seq(as.Date(min(ACTIVE_USERS$DATE_CREATION)),as.Date(max(ACTIVE_USERS$DATE_CREATION)),by = 1))
colnames(Axis_X_Date) <- c("DATE_CREATION")

Axis_X_Date <- merge(Axis_X_Date, ACTIVE_USERS, by = "DATE_CREATION", all.x =TRUE , all.y = FALSE)
ACTIVE_USERS <- Axis_X_Date
rm(Axis_X_Date)
colnames(ACTIVE_USERS) <- c("DATE_CREATION", "USER_ID", "DATE_DELETION")
```

Then I calculate the "Age" for each day.

```
ACTIVE_USERS$Age_Days <- ACTIVE_USERS$DATE_DELETION - ACTIVE_USERS$Date
```

And then I create a for loop, and apply the following actions for each row of the dataframe:

```
table_page_all <- data.frame()

for(i in 1:nrow(ACTIVE_USERS)){
  
  # To simplify, I convert NAs of DATE_DELETION, meaning still active accounts, as active until today
  ifelse( is.na(ACTIVE_USERS$DATE_DELETION[i] ), ACTIVE_USERS$DATE_DELETION[i] <- today_date, ACTIVE_USERS$DATE_DELETION[i]) 
  
  # here I replicate USER_ID for each day where USER_ID was alive/active
  Dates_Active <- seq(ACTIVE_USERS$Date[i], ACTIVE_USERS$DATE_DELETION[i], by="days")
  Ref_ID <- rep(ACTIVE_USERS$USER_ID[i], length(Dates_Active))
  
  # I combine these USER_ID and Dates_Active for each row of the ACTIVE_USERS dataframe
  data_frame <- data.frame(Dates_Active, Ref_ID)
  
  table_page_all  <- rbind(table_page_all, data_frame)
  
  cat('Row: ', i , 'out of', nrow(ACTIVE_USERS), '\n')
  
}
```

Comment: (1) Please test the code you give us, this sample data has an extra comma. (2) Please search SO for "summarize by group", this is almost certainly a dupe of those. (3) If not, it may help to have data where at least one day has a count over 1, show your expected output, and why this summarizing is distinct (i.e., not a dupe).

Comment: (4) You are misusing `ifelse`, never attempt assignment inside of it. If you are not explicitly targeting vectorized comparisons, always use `if` (and `else`). (4) Iteratively `rbind`ing frames scales very poorly, search for "R Inferno" then read the section on "Growing Objects".

Comment: Thanks a lot @r2evans - your comments triggered a deep dive on your references and helped me improve the speed and quality of my code. What really improved the speed is the use of `data.frame(rbindlist(my.list))`